# Filtering a date that's in a json string

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I am trying to build a filter which will create an audience of contacts that are 72 hours away from moving house. The relevant details I need for are in a field which is populated with a JSON string. The string contains a bunch of things but the most relevant to this question is

"movingDate" : "yyyy-mm-dd"

How can I create a filter so it only selects contacts where that date is 3 days in the future?

Comment: You could possibly use SQL parse json functions to create a query to accomplish this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you can't. To be able to use a DE filter you would need to first get that date out of your json string, format it appropriately and put and into a separate DE field with Date datatype. Depending on your scenario, you could use a query or script activity in order to do this.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.